# preventing user click on "X" close button on xpages form

Tags: jquery, dojo, xpages, xpages-ssjs

i Search in stackoverflow, found Dojo version to prevent Esc to close xPage tab in client.

```
<xp:eventHandler
        event="onClientLoad"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[dojo.addOnLoad( function(){ 
 dojo.connect( document, 'keydown', function(e){  
         if(e.keyCode === 27){ dojo.stopEvent(e); }        
 });
});]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
```

But if i want to prevent user click on "X" = "close" button on top of form to close the window. Got anyway to blur out the "X" button? or make the window cannot close by clicking on it?

Comment: you really need to be more specific:what kind of client are you talking about: Browser? Notes? Mobile? - Whaat's the relation of the "X" in regards to the client: is it closing a browser or client tab? Or the entire window? Or is it maybe a modal dialog like a dojoDialog?

Comment: google chrome browser, if possible notes client as well.(reason, allow user to select either run online / on office use.)  The tab open is xpages form. not using "extension library dialog" to call it.

Answer (score 1):

And if you mean to prevent a browser tab to close, I think it isn't really possible. Maybe it can be done but then there are a lot of pitfalls.

You can use the *onunload* event that's triggered whenever an object is unloaded. You can also use the *onbeforeunload* event that's supposed to be triggered when an element is loaded (but I found it to be unreliable).

The tricky part is: why does the unload happen? Is it because of the x, or because you have some programmatic action that reloads (part of) the screen? In both cases, an unload is triggered.

Comment: yeah i have some programmatic action use in the page, so i have to prevent user to click "x" (close) function. User can either click on "submit" or "cancel" button in screen. so that can update the action. I will try to learn how the onunload function use, see it suit my case or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the "x" on the Notes Client tab, you won't be able to do that within an XPages application's code.

It's opened as an Eclipse View (same as Applications Navigator, Controls Palette, Problems etc. in Designer). You would have to look at Eclipse APIs and see if it's possible to launch a View without the "x" to close it. But then you would need to launch the form from your XPage using an Eclipse call using XSP.executeCommand() and a plugin (minimum R9). See Mastering XPages 2nd Edition for the only example I know of for XSP.executeCommand().

Answer (score 0):

As the others already wrote: I don't think you really can solve it that way. Because: it won't be enough to prevent users from closing a tab, they might as well be closing the entire browser window (possibly incl. Notes Client window). And what if the browser / client crashes on them? No way to catch that "event" really.
I think you'll need to think it all over again.

Comment: ok thanks. I think really need to think of other way doing it.